# Bypassing an error inside a loop in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I have a dummy script below:

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3
e <- 5

list <- letters[1:5]

for (loop in (1:length(list)))
    {print(paste(list[loop],get(list[loop]),sep="-"))
    }

> source('~/.active-rstudio-document')
[1] "a-1"
[1] "b-2"
[1] "c-3"
Error in get(list[loop]) : object 'd' not found
```

Currently I have a problem that since `d` is not present, so an error message pop up and block the processing of `e`.

I wonder if R has some kind of "error handling", that is to bypass the error due to `d`, keep processing `e`, then return the error message when all valid data are processed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `exists` to check whether a variable exists:

```
for (loop in (1:length(list))){
  if(exists(list[loop])){
    print(
        paste(list[loop], get(list[loop]), sep="-"))
  }
}

[1] "a-1"
[1] "b-2"
[1] "c-3"
[1] "e-5"
```

More generally, R has a sophisticated mechanism for catching and dealing with errors.  See `?tryCatch` and its simplified wrapper, `?try`, for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as in most developed languages, there is such a mechanism. Check `?try`.